# I want to update my date every wednesday at 12:00 A.M. in the dropdown in php

Tags: php, datetime

I want to update my date every wednesday at 12:00 A.M. in the dropdown in php and remains unchanged till next wednesday.

Following is my code:

```
$now    = time(); // current timestamp
$today  = date("w", $now); // "w" returns the weekday (number)
$wednesday = 3; // 5th day of the week (sunday = 0)

if ($today == $wednesday) {
    $ts       = $now; // today is wednesday, don't change the timestamp
    $daysLeft = 0; // no days left!
} else {

    $daysLeft = $wednesday-$today; // get the left days
    $ts = $now + 84600 * $daysLeft; // now + seconds of one day * days left
}

?>

<h1>
    Forecast for <?php echo date("Y-m-d", $ts) ?>
</h1>
```

In it date remains unchanged on wednesday which is correct and then change quickly as soon as thursday begins. Although I want it to remain same till next wednesday.

Comment: Save it on a database and run a cronjob to update it as soon as Thursday begins. P.S.

Comment: You want `$ts` to be today (if today is Wednesday) and the coming Wednesday if any other day?

Comment: Thanks Pedro, but the date will be changed only when entries will be added to db not before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating the issue.

```
<?php
$today = time();
$nextWed = strtotime('next wednesday');

if(date('D', $today) === 'Wed') {
    $ts = date('Y-m-d', $today);
} else {
    $ts = date('Y-m-d', $nextWed);
}
echo '<h1>Forecast for '.$ts.'</h1>';
?>
```

What's happening?

1. Get timestamp for today
2. Get timestamp for next Wednesday
3. If today is Wednesday, `$ts` = today's date
4. If today is NOT Wednesday, `$ts` = next Wednesday's date
5. Echo your results

**EDIT**

```
<?php
$now = time();
$today = date('Y-m-d', $now);
if(date('D', $now) === 'Wed') { $nextWed = strtotime($today); }
if(date('D', $now) === 'Thu') { $nextWed = strtotime("$today - 1 days"); }
if(date('D', $now) === 'Fri') { $nextWed = strtotime("$today - 2 days"); }
if(date('D', $now) === 'Sat') { $nextWed = strtotime("$today - 3 days"); }
if(date('D', $now) === 'Sun') { $nextWed = strtotime("$today - 4 days"); }
if(date('D', $now) === 'Mon') { $nextWed = strtotime("$today - 5 days"); }
if(date('D', $now) === 'Tue') { $nextWed = strtotime("$today - 6 days"); }
$ts = date('Y-m-d', $nextWed);
echo '<h1>Forecast for '.$ts.'</h1>'
?>
```

Comment: Thanks  Kuya. But i want date to be changed on sunday for next wed, can you plz edit this code...

Comment: Example: Today is Sunday 2015-10-11. Do you want the coming Wednesday 2015-11-14 or next Wednesday 2015-10-21? I'm getting confused because your question said you want to change the date on Wednesday.

Comment: Okay... please explain

Comment: Suppose today is Sunday (2015-10-11). We want the date to be changed to coming wed i.e 2015-10-14 and remains wed (2015-10-14) only for whole week until next wed(2015-10-21) comes as we are making enteries on wed, thursday and friday . Same procedure goes on and date will keep on changing every wed to that wed only.                       Hope it clears

Comment: I'm sorry but... you seem to be saying that you want it to change on Sunday (2015-110-11) to 2015-10-14 **and stay that way until 2015-10-21** (even after the 14th has passed)... but then you say the date will change on Wednesday. You want it to change every Sunday AND every Wednesday?

Comment: Let me see if I understand this... If it's Wed. then show today ... If it's Thu., Fri. or Sat. then show the **past** Wed. ... If it's Sun., Mon. or Tue. show the coming Wed.?

Comment: You can't tell Sunday the 11th to show the coming Wed. the 14th and at the same time tell Sun. the 18th NOT to show the coming Wed. the 21st. The script can only do what you tell it to do. If you tell Sun. to show the coming Wed. - that's exactly what it will do... so, on Sun. the 18th it's going to show  Wed. the 21st. - It's not going to keep showing the 14th because you already told it to show the coming Wed.

Comment: In short... you can't tell Sun. to change this week, but not change next week. You either tell it to change or not. And it will do the same week-after-week.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92234/discussion-between-sonia-and-kuya).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time.
See today is wednesday so procedure goes like as follows:

Wed: 2015-10-14
Thur:2015-10-14
Fri: 2015-10-14
Sat: 2015-10-14
Sun:2015-10-14
Mon:2015-10-14
Tues:2015-10-14
Wed:2015-10-21 (See here date will be changed and will remain same for other days till next wed)
Thur:2015-10-21
Fri:2015-10-21
and so on

Comment: So date will change on Wednesday

Comment: You're welcome Sonia. If this has helped you and answered your question please don't forget to accept it as your answer. :)

Comment: At the left of my answer you will see up and down arrows with score of 1. Just below that you should see a grey checkmark. Click the grey checkmark and it will turn green. That means you have accepted my answer. Happy Coding !